# css-loader localIdentName option forbids default class styles

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack, sass, css-loader

After i add localIdentName option to css-loader i can not longer style my classes without :local or :global, also all styles from node_modules are not applying to html element.
This works:

```
const styles = require("./styles.scss)" // import
:local .myclass { } // style in styles.scss
<div className={styles["myClass"]}></div> // html container
```

This doesn't:

```
import "./styles.scss"
.myclass { }
<div className="myClass"></div>
```

Here's my webpack config

```
 {
    loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
    options: {
       hmr: isDevMode
    },
 },
 {
   loader: 'css-loader',
      options: {
        modules: {
          localIdentName: '[path][name]__[local]--[hash:base64:5]',
        }
   }
 },
   'postcss-loader',
   'sass-loader',
 ],
```